# unable to install pymorph

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to install 'pymorph' on mac os x with 'PIP':

```
sudo pip install pymorph
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
NameError: name 'execfile' is not defined    
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in 
/private/tmp/pip-build-9hjd5tfm/pymorph/
```

I have read that using a python version different from 2.7 could lead to this kind of problem. Yet, I'm using the 2.7 version:

```
python --version
Python 2.7.13
```

Any ideas to solve this issue ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Maybe the `pip` launcher script is from a Python installation different from the Python 2.7 one invoked by `python`? Try `pip -V` to confirm this.

Comment: This could happen for example by: installing a Python 3.x distribution that includes `pip`, then installing a 2.7 one that doesn't. (That said, pip was included in Pythons since 2.7.9.)

Comment: You are right. It appears that the 'pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)' is used. How can I put the 2.7 as the default PIP?

Comment: If you want to do things Properly, and don't have another reason to install the package globally, use a virtual environment based on the 2.7 installation. (It's been a while since I actively did Python, so I'm not sure what solution is the one to use these days, I remember using `virtualenv`.) That way you only use the full path to the 2.7 python once, then activate that env in your shell and "python", "pip" etc. will point into the env's base installation.

Comment: This guide recommends pipenv, which seems pretty sane: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/

Comment: It's a good idea. I'm going to see how can I do this. Thank you

Comment: I'll go answerify this, since I started with a wild guess.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to have a `pip` command on your PATH that comes from a different Python installation than the `python` command. (Each entry script to a Python-based tool is bound to the Python installation that was used to install the package that provided it. This means that the `pip` command does *not* search PATH for a python installation.) If this `pip` comes up later on `PATH` than `python`, it would lead to behaviour that you describe.

This can happen, say, if you first install a Python 2.7 without `pip`, and then a Python 3.x with `pip`, if the installers prepend to PATH.

You can verify which version of Python `pip` is using and where it's installed by running `pip -V`.

The robust solution to this should be using a virtual environment that lets you tie the base python installation and libraries specific to your application alone with your project, as well as avoid cluttering your global `site-packages`, and prevent inadvertent compatibility issues from different versions of the same package being needed by different projects.

It seems that the current (as of late 2017) recommended virtual environment solution is [Pipenv](https://github.com/kennethreitz/pipenv). A decent-looking introduction to virtual environments using Pipenv, by the author of Pipenv, can be found [here](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/).